# Getting python usage errors using Django to display a table of files in a directory

Tags: python, html, django

So I am trying to get Django to display a template that shows a list of files on a local directory. My views.py looks like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from os import listdir 
def index(request):
    files = listdir("/path/to/directory/")
    filelen = len(files)
    return render(request, 'path/to/template.html')
```

My html template looks like this:

```
{%for i in range(1, filelen)%}
<tr>
    <td>{{i}}</td>
    <td>{{files[i]}}</td>
    {% if "a" in files[i] %}
        <td>✓</td>
    {% else %}
        <td>x</td>
    {% endif %}
    {% if "b" in files[i] %}
        <td>✓</td>
    {% else %}
        <td>x</td>
{% endif %}
```

But when I try to run it I get the following error:

```
Error at line 39
'for' statements should use the format 'for x in y': for i in range(1, len_files)
```

Anybody know how to get this to work? I have tried replacing filelen with {{filelen}} but that gave me the same error.

Comment: If the answer helped you, please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the `range()` function in the template. Rather do the following.
In your view.py add the following:

```
def index(request):
   files = listdir("/path/to/directory/")
   filelen = len(files)
   return render(request, 'path/to/template.html', {'filelen': filelen})
```

and then in your template loop using that range number as follows:

```
{%for i in filelen %}
 ...
{% endfor %}
```